# How to know how many users are online using multithreading and tcp socket in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm makeing a game online using java socket and I don't know how to `FrmServer` can set label for number of users are logged in. In each `EchoThread` will handle for a client and has a `public static ArrayList<EchoThread> clients = new ArrayList<>();` to solve the division of rooms for gaming.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        FrmServer frmServer = new FrmServer(); // this frame server need to know how many clients are logged in
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O error: " + e);
            }
            // new thread for a client
            EchoThread echoThread = new EchoThread(socket);
            echoThread.start();
        }
    }
```

How can I trigger the form server to know that a user has successfully logged in and increase the label value or decrease it if the user disconnects?

**NOTE:** I handled login and disconnection and it both resolved in EchoThread

Answer (score 0):

I did it, I just need to pass `frmServer` object to EchoThread and call setLabel function from within Echothread too.

```
EchoThread echoThread = new EchoThread(socket, frmServer);
```